Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED in react native app

Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
239 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 237 up-to-date
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
^
symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
location: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
^
symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
location: package com.swmansion.rnscreens
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
^
symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
location: class PackageList
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
new RNScreensPackage(),
^
symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
location: class PackageList
4 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
^
symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
location: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
^
symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
location: package com.swmansion.rnscreens
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
^
symbol:   class RNGestureHandlerPackage
location: class PackageList
/Users/venkat/Documents/React Native/Cadabams/cc-android/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
new RNScreensPackage(),
^
symbol:   class RNScreensPackage
location: class PackageList
4 errors
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
I tried to run the app in both emulator and device, getting above error.
